# Is ``to get more practice of the concept of management" correct?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following statements is grammatically correct?
A. Let us bring another example to get more practice of the concept of management.
B. Let us bring another example to get more practice in the concept of management.
C. Let us bring another example to get more practicing of the concept of management.
D. Let us bring another example to get more practicing in the concept of management.
E. None of them above. In this case do you have any idea how to write it correctly?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to practise a concept. (Or to get practice of a concept.) You can *understand* a concept, and I suppose you could practise attempting to understand a concept or practise employing a concept, but I don't see how you could ever practise a concept directly. So, what is it that you're trying to describe with the variations of the sentence in the question? What are you *actually* practising? (My own interpretation would be to write *to get more practice in management*, dropping *concept* altogether.)

Comment: I'm additionally unclear on the use of *let us bring another example* in this specific context. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Hi Jason thanks for your comment. Let us assume that we are writing an article about management. So we define the concept of management first. And then we bring some examples to distinguish between the concept of management and other concepts that they are misunderstood with the concept of management such as concept of boss. This is the context for the question I asked.

Comment: *Examples of the concept of management* is fine. But ***the practice of*** *the concept of management* remains unclear.

Comment: Thank you Jason. Your comment makes sense and is helpful.